# Encriptar y desencriptar contraseñas en wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, wordpress, md5

Resulta que estoy haciendo una aplicación de una pagina que esta hecha en wordpress

La plataforma principal en la cual se registran los usuarios es wordpress, y se supone que desde la app pueden también ingresar y loguearse, pero me surgió el inconveniente, de que no puedo comparar la contraseña desde la app por que  se supone que la contraseña que se crea desde wordpress, estaba en MD5, pero al revisar la tabla de wp_users el campo user_pass no contiene como tal un MD5, sino una criptografia diferente..

Hasta donde tengo entendido, uno puede crear los usuarios desde Mysql, usando la función MD5, lo que genera un valor (como este 4fc71da499f4... ) en ese campo user_pass, pero después que el usuario se loguea en wordpress, el valor de ese campo cambia a uno como este $P$BZryzhmZgg....

Hay alguna forma de saber como se genera esa contraseña o como puedo hacer una comparación de esa contraseña con los datos de ingreso desde la APP?

Comment: la contraseña se genera con un hash https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f57e182c87d545d1059b656a2b1dd6cb128b7ee8/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L225 . tal vez te convenga usar XML-RPC para acceder al wordpress https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support